# Accepting Donations For Your Charity In BITCOIN

Tags: donation

The tutorial is here: https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/tutorials/donations

First step: Sign up for a Coinbase account

Problem: "Merchant Services: We're no longer accepting new merchant services businesses. Stay tuned for new offerings that are coming soon."the

Is there currently a way to enable BitCoin donations for my favorite charity? I wanted to use Coinbase because they will generate a donor letter which will enable the contribution to be tax deductible in the U.S. While it is possible to create a wallet and publish the QR Code, it will be non-trivial to return Donor Letters and to immediately convert the Bitcoins into USD and to automatically deposit the donation into the nonprofit's checking account.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use btcpayserver. Fully non-custodial bitcoin payment processor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other service like [blockonomics](https://blog.blockonomics.co/how-to-create-a-bitcoin-donate-button-578f4f0c15f8) to create donation buttons to get payments directly to your wallet